# Create a Radio Station on Alexa

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm new developing Alexa skills. I've just followed some tutorials and customized them a little bit.

I followed [this](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player) tutorial, and it works nicely.

However, I was listening to a local radio station of my State (Antenne Bayern), which has an Alexa Skill and I was wondering if I could do something like that.

In the tutorial I linked, you can play a "podcast" and there, you can play different songs of the postcard. But now, I would like that when you go to the skill "Alexa, start AudioPlayer" you have two options, either "live radio" or a podcast list.

If you decide the live radio, alexa begins to stream the live transmission, if you decide the podcast list, then you have to decide which podcast. And I would also like, that you have to decide the song in the podcast (as in the AudioPlayer tutorial)

I mean, I would like something like this:

```
{
    "Live Radio": play_live_transmission(),
    "Podcast List": {
        "First Podcast": {
            "First Song": play_song_1(),
            "Second Song": play_song_2(),
        },
        "Second Podcast": {
            "First Song": play_song_3(),
            "Second Song": play_song_4(),
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to play the songs, but I don't know how should be the skill configured to have a structure like that.

I was reading [this post](http://moduscreate.com/build-an-alexa-skill-with-python-and-aws-lambda/) and I notice that he uses "GetStatus", "GetElevators" and "GetTrainTimes" with a list inside, and all that in the "intents".

Maybe I should do something like that. But I don't have any idea.

Maybe someone tried to do something similar and could help me. Maybe a documentation or an idea how should I write the skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with [flask-ask](https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask). I create an intent with a list of emissions. Then, when the user says "Alexa, start `Radio` with `some emission`" it searches the links of the emission. With [this tutorial](https://blog.craftworkz.co/flask-ask-a-tutorial-on-a-simple-and-easy-way-to-build-complex-alexa-skills-426a6b3ff8bc) it's quite easy to do it.